# Objective C: Copy file or folder from url to new folder

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm building an archiver for all data copied or cut on os x.  How do I copy the the file or directory stored at the fileUrl to a new directory?  An example of the URL I'm getting right now is file:///.file/id=6562758.59150379

```
NSArray *fileUrl = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSURL class], nil];
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionary];

//pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSArray *object1 = [pasteboard readObjectsForClasses:fileUrl options:options];

if (object1 != nil){
    NSLog(@"%@", object1);
}

2014-02-27 12:31:22.451 Copy&Cut Archive[17720:303] (
    "file:///.file/id=6562758.59150379"
)
```

Comment: Make your life easier: `NSArray *fileURLs = @[[NSURL class]];
NSArray *objects = [pasteboard readObjectsForClasses:fileURLs @{}];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
This is how I copied the file or directory to a new folder.

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionary];
NSArray *fileURL = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSURL class], nil];
NSArray *object1 = [pasteboard readObjectsForClasses:fileURL options:options];

if ([object1 count] > 0){
    NSURL *frURL_source = [object3 objectAtIndex:0];

    //convert file reference URL to path-based URL
    NSURL *fpURL_source = [frURL_source filePathURL];

    //dirName is NSString path to the archive directory
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", dirName, toWrite];

    NSURL *fpURL_dest = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    [fm copyItemAtURL:fpURL_source toURL:fpURL_dest error:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually using the pasteboard makes sense, but under the hood it would be better to forgo the pasteboard and use [`NSFileManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsfilemanager_class/reference/reference.html)'s methods for moving and copying files.

You've got a few options...

### Moving and Copying Items

`– copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:`

`– copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:`

`– moveItemAtURL:toURL:error:`

`– moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:`